# Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: facebook graph api, photo to album

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook graph api to upload photos to existing album in my account. 
Here is my code how i am doing.

```
$fb = new Facebook(array(
                    'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxx',
                    'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
                    'cookie' => 'true'
    ));

$fb->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$imagePath='C:\\wamp\\www\\photo\\photo.jpg';


    $args = array('message' => 'photo caption is...');
    $args['image'] = $imagePath;
    $data = $fb->api('/'. '5463871911515666183' . '/photos?access_token='. $user_access_token, 'POST', $args);

    print_r($data);
```

when i execute this it shows an error

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: 5463871911515666183 thrown in C:\wamp\www\photo\facebook-php-sdk\src\base_facebook.php on line 970

Comment: @hello I am facing same kind of problem ..to get album photos I am using FQL and to get I am trying to use Graph API .

Comment: @hello I am facing same kind of problem ..to get album photos I am using FQL and to get I am trying to use Graph API .Someone give me an sample https://graph.facebook.com/98423808305/comments where 98423808305 is pid. but in my sample when I am using same , it returning me blank JSON array ...pls let me know if any suggetsion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem has been solved , i was fetching album IDs using FQL, in which id of an album is represented as **'aid'**, While in the GRAPH API album id is represented as **'id'** while uploading image to an album i am using Graph API, the same object in the FQL and Graph is represented in different.
In the FQL , **object_id** is equavlent to the Graph API **id**.